# Abelian group $A$ with $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A,\mathbb{Q})=\{0\}$. Is $A$ a torsion group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be an abelian group such that $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(A,\mathbb{Q})=\{0\}$. Is $A$ a torsion group? Can you give me a hint how to prove it?
Regards

Comment: Can you do it if $A$ is finitely generated?

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is not torsion, it has a subgroup $B$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. There is a nonzero homomorphism $B\to\mathbb{Q},$ which extends to a homomorphism $A\to\mathbb{Q}$ (because $\mathbb{Q}$ is injective in the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules).